# Does keyboard maestro have a trace/verbose log?

Tags: automation

I was experimenting with the "Highlight Location" action of Keyboard Maestro  yesterday. It worked.
Today it's not working.
How can I troubleshoot keyboard maestro?
When I press the play button on a macro, and nothing happens, is there an internal log I can inspect maybe?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Keyboard Maestro debugger. Look under start for start debugging. You can single step through your script.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard Maestro has logs available without needing the debugger. You can find them by going to **Help » Open Logs Folder** as shown here:

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard Maestro menu]

That will open "$HOME/Library/Logs/Keyboard Maestro" which will show you two files:

1. Editor.log
2. Engine.log

You probably want the "Engine.log".

If that does not help, the debugger (as suggested already) would be a good next step.

---

FYI - there is also a very active forum at https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com which has a number of helpful Keyboard Maestro users, and the developer himself is often there as well.